# Using Atlas MongoDB as an AWS Data Migration Server Data Provider

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-atlas, dms

I am trying to follow the AWS instructions and create an import/conversion service from an Atlas Mongo database to and RDS instance of Postgres.

Working my way through the instructions, I have found that there appears to be noway (using the DMS console) choose an external Mongo instance as a source.

Is this correct.

If it is correct, are there some work arounds -- for instance exporting Mongo Data to an S3 bucket as a parquet or similar format and then using that as a source?